# Cannot invoke a function that change or retrieve function of a chaincode?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

**Problem:**

I have created a Hyperledger fabric network with six organizations 2 peers for each. After running the network I install fabcar chaincode on one peer of each organization and then I instantaited the chaincode using this command.

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -n fabcar -l node -v 1.0  -c '{"Args":["init"]}' -C myc -P "AND ('Org2MSP.peer','Org1MSP.peer',Org3MSP.peer','Org4MSP.peer','Org5MSP.peer','Org6MSP.peer')"
```

Up to this command, everything was successfully happened without giving me an error. After I tried to invoke a function using this command.

```
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C myc -n fabcar -c '{"Args":["initLedger"]}
```

This command leaves this error on the particular peer logs.

> 2019-05-12 13:38:01.162 UTC [gossip.privdata] StoreBlock -> INFO 191
>   [myc] Received block [8] from buffer 2019-05-12 13:38:01.213
>   UTC [vscc] Validate -> ERRO 192 VSCC error:
>   stateBasedValidator.Validate failed, err validation of endorsement
>   policy for chaincode fabcar in tx 8:0 failed: signature set did not
>   satisfy policy 2019-05-12 13:38:01.213 UTC [committer.txvalidator]
>   validateTx -> ERRO 193 VSCCValidateTx for transaction txId =
>   a17c0deb20af5a4e0a232fa432ea13e74fca101b63cb697384bbaced80905773
>   returned error: validation of endorsement policy for chaincode fabcar
>   in tx 8:0 failed: signature set did not satisfy policy 2019-05-12
>   13:38:01.258 UTC [committer.txvalidator] Validate -> INFO 194
>   [myc] Validated block [8] in 96ms 2019-05-12 13:38:01.259 UTC
>   [valimpl] preprocessProtoBlock -> WARN 195 Channel [trafficfine]:
>   Block [8] Transaction index [0] TxId
>   [a17c0deb20af5a4e0a232fa432ea13e74fca101b63cb697384bbaced80905773]
>   marked as invalid by committer. Reason code
>   [ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE]

This was the logs on the chincode.

> fabcar@1.0.0 start /usr/local/src
>   node fabcar.js "--peer.address" "peer0.org2.example.com:9052"
>
> 2019-05-12T13:35:08.951Z info [lib/chaincode.js]
>   info: Registering with peer peer0.org2.example.com:9052 as chaincode
>   "fabcar:1.0" {"timestamp":"2019-05-12T13:35:08.951Z"}
>   2019-05-12T13:35:09.232Z info [lib/handler.js]
>   info: Successfully registered with peer node. State transferred to
>   "established" {"timestamp":"2019-05-12T13:35:09.232Z"}
>   2019-05-12T13:35:09.234Z info [lib/handler.js]
>   info: Successfully established communication with peer node. State
>   transferred to "ready" {"timestamp":"2019-05-12T13:35:09.234Z"}
>   =========== Instantiated fabcar chaincode =========== 2019-05-12T13:35:09.240Z info [lib/handler.js]
>   info: [myc-8ecdb2a5] Calling chaincode Init() succeeded. Sending
>   COMPLETED message back to peer
>   {"timestamp":"2019-05-12T13:35:09.240Z"} { fcn: 'initLedger', params:
>   [] }
>   ============= START : Initialize Ledger =========== successful { status: 200, message: '', payload:  } Added <-->  { make:
>   'Toyota',   model: 'Prius',   color: 'blue',   owner: 'Tomoko',
>   docType: 'car' } successful { status: 200, message: '', payload:
>    } Added <-->  { make: 'Ford',   model: 'Mustang',   color:
>   'red',   owner: 'Brad',   docType: 'car' } successful { status: 200,
>   message: '', payload:  } Added <-->  { make: 'Hyundai',
>   model: 'Tucson',   color: 'green',   owner: 'Jin Soo',   docType:
>   'car' } successful { status: 200, message: '', payload:  }
>   Added <-->  { make: 'Volkswagen',   model: 'Passat',   color:
>   'yellow',   owner: 'Max',   docType: 'car' } successful { status: 200,
>   message: '', payload:  } Added <-->  { make: 'Tesla',
>   model: 'S',   color: 'black',   owner: 'Adriana',   docType: 'car' }
>   successful { status: 200, message: '', payload:  } Added <-->
>   { make: 'Peugeot',   model: '205',   color: 'purple',   owner:
>   'Michel',   docType: 'car' } successful { status: 200, message: '',
>   payload:  } Added <-->  { make: 'Chery',   model: 'S22L',
>   color: 'white',   owner: 'Aarav',   docType: 'car' } successful {
>   status: 200, message: '', payload:  } Added <-->  { make:
>   'Fiat',   model: 'Punto',   color: 'violet',   owner: 'Pari',
>   docType: 'car' } successful { status: 200, message: '', payload:
>    } Added <-->  { make: 'Tata',   model: 'Nano',   color:
>   'indigo',   owner: 'Valeria',   docType: 'car' } successful { status:
>   200, message: '', payload:  } Added <-->  { make: 'Holden',
>   model: 'Barina',   color: 'brown',   owner: 'Shotaro',   docType:
>   'car' }
>   ============= END : Initialize Ledger =========== 2019-05-12T13:37:58.998Z info [lib/handler.js]
>   info: [myc-a17c0deb] Calling chaincode Invoke() succeeded. Sending
>   COMPLETED message back to peer
>   {"timestamp":"2019-05-12T13:37:58.998Z"}

I tried a lot to figure out what is wrong with my network. But I was unable to find out. can someone help me to solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your endorsement policy is an AND policy so you will need to collect endorsement from all the Organizations defined in your policy. You can use [--peerAddresses] flag in your invoke command to send the transaction to multiple peers in different organizations and get the required signatures required for the policy.

Comment: For that, I need to provide tlsrootcerts isn't it can you give me sample command with these two flags. Becuse when I put tlsrootcert array it says no such file or directory.

Comment: I specify it like this.`'/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt'`

Comment: An example command for invoking chaincode with two organizations:

--peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 peer0.org2.example.com:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt

If it says there is no such file or directory then you can use "docker exec " command to ssh into your peer machine and confirm if the file exists or not.

Comment: Also make sure whether TLS is enabled and whether TLS environment variables are have been set in your docker compose file